# How do I launch a GNOME GUI application as root?

Tags: root, gnome3, gui

I tried doing it the macOS way by trying to drop it into a Terminal window but didn't quite work. In the Mac apps are self-contained; I hand't really thought about it on Linux but even so I woulnd't know where to begin.

Right now I'm logging off, logging in as root modify what's needed and back to user, as you may know it gets old real fast. I know how to launch stuff on Terminal as root, I just don't know where apps are generally or how to extract their icon in the Activities overlay/menu if it's a huge chaotic shortcut mess like Windows.

I'm using Fedora 28 & RHEL 7.5, BTW -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gksudo` or `gksu` to run graphical applications as root inside your current graphical non-root session.

See also:

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/11766/819150
2. https://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo

Comment: I thought I'd be getting an email but didn't, that's weird, ServerFault does send me emails. Anyway, I appreciate your help, but I sort of had figured that out already. See, in macOS, I know usually apps are dropped in /Applications/{appname}/Contents/MacOS/{binaries}, at least for the most part. So I know what to issue after changing user or doing a privilege-elevation command. Even Windows sort of does the same... and I happily do it in Linux except that I don't know where apps are installed. The apps presented by GNOME in the drawer? The overlay it has.

Comment: And thanks for the links, I'm hooked on it already. :)

Comment: link 1, helps solved my issue, thanks

Comment: `gksudo` and `gksu` [have been removed](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=268140&hilit=gksudo) from Ubuntu since 18.10.